# Spinner background with states not working

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to set a custom background to the spinner:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

spinner_bg.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="#ff0000"/>
    <item android:drawable="#00ff00"/>
</selector>
```

I saw a lot of tutorials and articles that are doing such thing, but in my case it
somehow doesn't work, I just got plain text without any states and backgorund, if I set color or 9-patch to the `background` all works fine. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: I have tried all suggestions, but it doesn't help, also Android Studio pointing out that something is wrong, but no hint available.

**Edit2**: I found the problem. I missed .xml extension for the spinner_bg file in my source. Also [Mou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4296783/mou) had right correction that I should use drawable instead of color, so I marked his answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in spinner_bg.xml.

**android:drawable** must be a reference to a drawable and not a **color**.

Try creating a shape drawable or another drawable (9-path) and setting it correctly in the xml.

EDIT:

Something like this:

spinner_bg_color.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFF0000"/>
</shape>
```

And setting this drawable like background drawable in spinner_bg.xml

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
android:drawable="#00ff00"
```

to

```
android:color="#00ff00"
```

like so:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ff0000"/>
    <item android:color"#00ff00"/>
</selector>
```